# how to pass html in json data to from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I want to pass html in json data.While retrieving the data in view, the html code is also being printed as a string.How can i show a url in json message.

Controller code:

```
                    $jsarr['msg'] = 'you have not yet - register here <a href="member/register">Register</a>';
                    $jsarr['redirect'] = 0;
                    echo json_encode($jsarr);
             }
```

In Ajax Success :

```
   if(data.result == 'success'){
         //some code
   }else{
        $(".error").text(data.msg);
   }
```

Got the solution:
In jquery,instead of text I used html

```
 if(data.result == 'success'){
     //some code
 }else{
    $(".error").html(data.msg);
}
```

Comment: `jQuery.parseHTML()` can be used. You can pass the html string to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly It can be like 
Controller:

```
$html='<html>
       <head>
       </head>
      <body>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      </body>
     </html>';
echo json_encode($html);
```